# Calling navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() freezes my NextJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, geolocation

in my NextJS app, I'm trying to get the geolocation of the user on the click of a button:

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
  // For this example, let's assume 'geolocation' is in navigator.
  const ask = useCallback(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      () => console.log('success'),
      (error) => console.log('error =', error),
    );
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={ask}>Click</button>
}
```

When I click on the button, nothing happens. The only way I can get my 'success' in the console is to change the current tab of my browser, or change the current window I'm working on and get back to my page so that it's being hot refreshed and shows me the correct result.

I don't understand this behaviour. In other words, if I Windows + Tab to go back to my code and then go back to the page after having clicked on the button, it works, otherwise nothing happens.

This problem is kind of solved when I add a timeout:

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
  const ask = useCallback(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      () => console.log('success'),
      (error) => console.log('error =', error),
      {timeout:5000},
    );
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={ask}>Click</button>
}
```

I get a `GeolocationPositionError` in the console (so the error callback is executed):

```
error = {code: 3, message: 'Timeout expired'}
```

but this should not happen. I know it works, but the user would need to change his tab and then go back to get the expected behaviour... in terms of UX it's a catastrophe.

Also, when I get back to the page after the Windows + Tab trick, the word 'success' is printed 10 times in the console because I clicked 10 times on the button.

I'm on NextJS with TypeScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was.

I was using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` in another component of my tree. The fact is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't work as expected when declaring `watchPosition`.

I should have used `clearWatch`.

Anyways, it's still a weird behaviour and I think I won't be the only one with this problem in the future, so I won't delete my post.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I try to help you - in my opinion you are using the onClick Event wrong!

Try

```
<button onClick={() => ask()}>Click</button>
```

Comment: My function ask() is called. If I add a `console.log('hi');` before `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` in my `ask` function, the word 'hi' is indeed printed in the console as expected.

Comment: really strange - did you try to add a check if navigator exists at the moment?
Something like 
f (navigator.geolocation) {} around the method

Comment: Yeah, it exists

Comment: Is the behaviour the same in other browsers? On other clients?

Comment: Yes, I tried on Brave and Chrome, also in the console, this behaviour happens there too. It look like it works 10% of the time as it should be and 90% of the time it doesn't do anything...

Comment: When I use your code just unter pages in an existing Next.js procect (MyComponent.tsx) and open the page in the browser to click on the button it works all the time correct ... ?? Sorry - no idea left from my side :/


https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0K9f.png